# Is this an issue? - base type 'Cirrious.CrossCore.Converters.MvxValueConverter<bool,bool>' is not CLS-compliant

Tags: mvvmcross, valueconverter

I have a portable class library that I am using MvvmCross in.  I thought it would be good to centralise various MvxValueConverter classes into this library as they will be used extended or used by different platforms/dlls.

For instance I created the class:-

```
namespace MyCompany.Core.ValueConverters
{
  public class InverseBoolValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, bool>
  {
    protected override bool Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return !value;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I am seeing however is that the output is throwing the following warning:-

warning CS3009: 'MyCompany.Core.ValueConverters.BoolValueConverter': base type 'Cirrious.CrossCore.Converters.MvxValueConverter' is not CLS-compliant.

I guess I am not sure if this is an issue or something that I can ignore and secondly - why is it not CLS complaint?

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Alan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My **guess** is simply that you have `[assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]` in your assembly while MvvmCross doesn't have that set - see [Base type is not CLS-compliant, what reasons of this warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013087/base-type-is-not-cls-compliant-what-reasons-of-this-warning)

If your project does care about interop with other languages and about strict CLS compliance, then there is a lot of info on it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3(v=vs.110).aspx#Generics and you can find more about it here by including the `C#` and `cls-compliant` tag - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cls-compliant

Comment: You are spot on Stuart with that.  I did not realise that one of my colleagues had enforced this into the AssembyInfo. Thanks.