# Project to project reference - type not CLS compliant

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem regarding a public declaration in one project which makes reference to a class in a different project.

The parent project references the dependent project without problem. However, I'm getting a warning that Type member 'user' is not CLS-compliant.  It's declared as

```
Public user As User
```

this declaration is made in the parent project.  User is a class in the supporting project
I can use the type on a form without fail.  Now, I try to pass it off on another form - in the parent project:

```
Private oldUser As User
oldUser = frmUserMgt.user
```

and the thing crashes.  Stepping through the code shows oldUser is nothing.

I built a brand new solution and tested this exchange without fail.  I've searched solution and project settings until I'm blue in the face and can't find a difference.  It's a VS2012 VB solution.  I can post as much code as needed if the above description isn't sufficient - any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Base type is not CLS-compliant, what reasons of this warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013087/base-type-is-not-cls-compliant-what-reasons-of-this-warning)

Comment: frmUserMgt is a *type name*, not an object reference.  This syntax is supported anyway in VB.NET but forever causes the kind of mishap you describe.  It has a knack for creating a *new* instance of the frmUserMgt class, especially when you run the code on a worker thread.  This doesn't otherwise do anything to solve the warning.

Comment: Hans, if it is causing a New instance of frmUserMgt what can I do to fix it so it's passing the correct instance.